# Python - platform-independent 5.1 Sound Library

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, multimedia

Is there any dolby/5.1/7.1 audio processing Python library? It would be best if it is platform independent.

Would be nice if it looks like:

```
import lib
f = lib.open("8channels_audiofile")
lib.play(from=f.channel3, to="left rear");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pysonic.sourceforge.net/ - this depends on FMOD, which is free for non-commercial use, and supported on many platforms.

See the FMOD website for details: http://www.fmod.org/